# Combining limits in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, sequence-of-function

Suppose I have a sequence of functions, $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, each of which is continuous about a value $a^*$. Suppose I define a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which tends to $a^*$. Is it true that:

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow a^*}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(a_n)$$

if both of the above limits exist. If so why? If not why not?

Comment: Do you know the concept of "uniform convergence" ?

Comment: I was looking at that but I don't need $f_n$ to converge everywhere to some function $f$.

Comment: LHS implies RHS (subset).  Reverse may need work.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Let $f_n(x) = x^n$, let $a=1$, and let $a_n = 2^{1/n}$. Then $f_n(a) = 1$ for all $n$, so the limit on the left is $1$. But $f_n(a_n) = 2$, so the limit on the right is $2$.

Comment: Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ near the point $x=1$ exist? It seems to need to exist for the LHS to exist. The other answer (provided by Jose Carlos Santos) is bounded, which allows that to exist. But, the limit function for your $f_n(x)$ near $x=1$ is $$\begin{cases}0 & 0<x<1 \\ 1 & x=1 \\ \infty & x>1\end{cases}$$, so the limit on the LHS should be $\infty$.